# Spring Validation Regex is allowing ampersand

Tags: regex, spring, validation, spring-boot

I am writing a validation logic for my input field and only alphanumeric characters, apostrophe ' and hyphen are allowed

```
public class SearchFilter implements Serializable {

@Pattern(regexp = "^[A-Za-z0-9'-]+$", message = "searchText should only contain alphanumeric values and ' and -")
private String searchText;

}
```

It's a Spring boot application so, in the controller method the validation is triggered with

```
public List<Result> search(@Valid SearchFilter filter) {
        //return searchService.search(filter);
    }
```

It is working fine for most scenarios and throwing a validation error but for reason & ampersand is allowed. I am not sure why. In the online regex evaluator

https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html

It is working fine, i.e & is not allowed.

Any idea why? I am using java 8 with Spring Boot 4.3

**UPDATE**

Based on response from  Andreas Lundgren, updated the regex to

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[\\x2DA-Za-z0-9\\x27]+$", message = "searchText 
should only contain alphanumeric values and ' and -")
```

It is still failing for Spring validation for &. I ran a test with Pattern class and all is working as expected, strings with & or anyother special chararacter except ' and - is failing

```
java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile("^[\\x2DA-Za-z0-9\\x27]+$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("Hello^s");
boolean b = m.matches();
System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: Just to make sure: does `;` also pass? Try replacing `'` with `\x27` (it should be `\\x27` inside the string literal).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks of your response. Yes, it rejects semi-colon too. The problem is with & only. replaced the apostrophe with \x27

Comment: If the regex engine is Lucene, try using `"[-A-Za-z0-9']+"`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because the `-` in the character class is used for describing a span in reg exp, thus it's a special character in a character class and must be escaped.

Test `"^[A-Za-z0-9'\\-]+$"`

Using a hyphens in a character class does not mean that the character class includes the character `-`, it means that the character class includes all characters in the ascii table between the character before and after the hyphens character. Compare how you wrote `a-z`.

Not sure what happens if you have it as the last character... Maybe different engines react differently on this. Example `'-,` is all characters between `'` (0x27) and `,` (0x2C) in the ascii table, for example `+` (0x2B).

Comment: hyphens are working fine whether i escape it or not. The problem is & is being allowed though i didn't add that in the regex

Comment: But using a hyphens in a character class does not mean that the character class includes the character `-`, it means that the character class includes all characters in the ascii table between the character before and after the hyphens character. I will clarify my answer.

Comment: I added the escape hex for hyphen at both first and last indexes yet same problem. This is working fine for java.util.regex.Pattern test, check my update. It may be a problem with Spring's implementation for @Pattern

Answer (score 0):

All,

It was a stupid mistake from my end. The error was only happening when calling via POSTMAN and realised that & is a query parameter delimitter in POSTMAN and hence the chararcter '&' was not being passed to the controller. If we pass %26 in POSTMAN, & is read as a character and validation is successful and throws a 400 error. It was not a regex issue. Thanks for all help